# Freemarker and RTF

Tags: rtf, freemarker

I´ll have to generate some docs file and to do that we are going to use templates from the preview version.  In my first test, I am using a simple java project to generate a new file based on the template.

It seems that the old version is based on freemarker, but I can´t find information how to use it with RTF files. Even the template file has the doc extension it is a RTF file.

The first step import the template is ok:

> 2013-09-09 20:21:43 DEBUG cache:83 - Compiling FreeMarker template "TEMPLATE.DOC"["pt_BR",Cp1252,parsed]  from "C:\templates\TEMAPLTE.DOC"

It checks if some variables linked to a condition exists on the data like:

> data.put("IS_MANDATORY", true);
>   And it shows or hide depending on it value

but the normal fields that should be changed/updated they still shown as their variables:

> $[NAME]$

I´ve tried to change it to:

> ${name} 
>   but it didin´t work.

I am not sure what I am missing, any idea?

Thanks and regards,

Eddiedu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enter `${name}` into a rich editor (like Word or WordPad), since `{` and `}` are reserved characters in RTF, it will become to `$\{name\}` in the saved file. (Open it with notepad to see.) To work this around, you will have to use a custom `TemplateLoader` implementation (via `Configuration.setTemplateLoader`) that wraps another `TemplateLoader` to wrap the `Reader` into a filter. This filter should look for `$\{`, and from there it should un-escape RTF until the closing `\}`.

Certainly the older templates with `$[NAME]$` did a similar `TemplateLoader` trick, only it has replaced `$[` and `]$` with `${` and `}`. That's kind of awkward, but I guess the author has found it easier to implement.

Comment: That already helped a lot.  Do you have any example how to do it?

Comment: Nothing at hand... but it's pretty self-explanatory if you look at the `TemplateLoader` API. But if there's a more concrete issue with it, ask.